# Django: Integrity error when deleting an object with a 'through' many-to-many field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am using a through table in a many-to-many field:

```
class EmailType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Email(models.Model):        
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(EmailType,blank=True,null=True,default='')

class EntityEmail(Email):        
    entity = models.ForeignKey("Entity")

class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    emails = models.ManyToManyField(Email,through="EntityEmail")
```

If I create a new Entity  and assign a new Email. Everything goes Ok.
But if I want to delete this entity from the admin, an integrity error is raised.

> Cannot delete or update a parent row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`thedb`.`theapp_entityemail`,
>   CONSTRAINT
>   `entity_id_refs_id_28f53d76782ad9c6`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES
>   `theapp_entity` (`id`))'

Everything is ok if I delete first the EntityEmail.

Is there a way to avoid this problem? I am using django 1.2 and I can't use the on_delete option of 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite [Model.delete()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/) method on the Entity model to match the `on_delete` functionality, if this is really what you are after.